# SphinxSe dont return multivalue if queries many index

Tags: search-engine, sphinx

I use SPHINXSE And I query many index (like explained by Barryhunter here  [Joining on Multiple SphinxSE Tables In Single Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317460/joining-on-multiple-sphinxse-tables-in-single-query) )

**My problem is**

In each index I have column with same name.

In my sphinxSe table I've fields named like these attributes.

When I run a query   on only one index, theses fields are filled, but not when I use many index.

I'st a problem, because I would use id to simply identify from wich index is found the row.

As it's perhaps bette with source, find below my conf, and queries

**in my sphinx.conf**

```
   source src_article_tv : article_base {
          sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
          sql_query = \
                 SELECT /* sphinx index search article_tv_base */ \
                         concat (id,'40'), \
                         id AS ressource_id, \
                         'article' AS ressource_type, \ (...)
         sql_attr_uint = ressource_id
         sql_attr_string = ressource_type

 (...)



source src_media_tv : media_base
{
        sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
        sql_query = \
                SELECT /* sphinx index search full media */ \
                        concat (o.id,'20'), \
                        o.id AS ressource_id, \
                        'media_tv' AS ressource_type, \
(...)

        sql_attr_uint = ressource_id
        sql_attr_string = ressource_type


delimiter $$
CREATE TABLE `tv_generic` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `weight` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `query` varchar(3072) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `ressource_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `ressource_type` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    KEY `query` (`query`(1024))
) ENGINE=SPHINX DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
CONNECTION='sphinx://127.0.0.1:9312/idx_tv'$$
```

So
with

```
SELECT * FROM search.tv_generic where query = 'mons;index=idx_article_tv';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM search.tv_generic where query = 'mons;index=idx_media_tv';
```

fields ressource_id & ressource_type are filled (with the good values)

but with

```
SELECT * FROM search.tv_generic where query = 'mons;index=idx_article_tv,idx_media_tv';
```

fields ressource_id & ressource_type are '0'

Comment: Have yu tried specifing both indexes in teh table CONNECTION='sphinx://127.0.0.1:9312/idx_article_tv,idx_media_tv'

Answer (score 0):

I Found a "dirty" solution.

```
compat_sphinxql_magics = 1
```

and it's work.

It's still dirty because

1. compat_sphinxql_magics = 1 is deprecated http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=9239
2. I don't understand myself  why  it's work with compat_sphinxql_magics = 1